# How to use DMA-BUF in Android on a Snapdragon chipset?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opencl, android-source

I have a library, developing it using NDK. Part of my computation is shared between CPU and GPU and DSP, so I need to make shared memory to reduce the copying between devices. I realized that there is DMA-Buf heap which is for the same job but I cannot add the header files to my project and link it against it. I downloaded the AOSP but not sure what I should do next.

Answer (score 0):

The headers you need are `dma-heap.h` and *possibly* also `dma-buf.h` depending on what else you want to do. They are available in the Android NDK at:

```
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/linux/dma-buf.h
./toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/linux/dma-heap.h
```